# Django: Update exsisting record with form=MyForm(instance=MyID) doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms, modelform

I'm try to update an existing record, i had create his Form, in the view I call 
EditRecipeForm(instance=Recipe.objects.get(id=recipe_id) but in the view don't appear 
the existing fields.

Here is the structure of the directory

```
rsg
├── src
|   ├── recipes
|   |   ├── forms
|   |   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   |   └── update.py
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   ├── admin.py
|   |   ├── models.py
|   |   ├── test.py
|   |   ├── urls.py
|   |   └── views.py
|   ├── rsg
|   |   └── ...
|   ├── signups
|   |   ├── ...
|   |   └── ...
|   └── magnate.py
├── static
    ├── media
    ├── static
    ├── static-only
    ├── templates
    |   ├── recipes
    |   |   ├── profileview.html
    |   |   ├── recipedit.html
    |   |   └── recipecreate.html
    |   ├── signups
    |   └── ....
    ├── ...
    └── index.hml
```

Here is the Recipe Models: from rsg/src/recpes/models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):

name = models.CharField('Nome',max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField('Presentazione', null=True, blank=True, default="")

directions = models.TextField('Preparazione', null=True, blank=True)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Data di Pubblicazione',auto_now_add=True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField('Data ultima modifica', auto_now_add=False, auto_now = True)
    img = models.ImageField('Immagine', upload_to="/static/Images/", null=True, blank=True)

    difficulty_grade = (
        ('bassa', 'bassa'),
        ('media', 'media'),
        ('alta', 'alta'),
        ('molto alta', 'molto alta'),
    )

    cost_size = (
         ('basso', 'basso'),
          ('medio', 'medio'),
           ('alto', 'alto'),
    )
    difficulty = models.CharField(smart_unicode('Difficoltà'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, choices=difficulty_grade)
    time_preparation = models.IntegerField('Preparazione', null=True, blank=True)
    time_preparation_min_h = models.CharField('Ore/minuti', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                                                choices=(('ore', 'h'),('minuti','min'),('giorni','gg'),))
    time_cooking = models.IntegerField('Cottura', null=True, blank=True)
    time_cooking_min_h = models.CharField('Ore/minuti', max_length=20, null=True, blank=True,
                                                choices=(('ore', 'h'),('minuti','min'),('giorni','gg'),))
    dose_for = models.CharField(smart_unicode('Dosi per'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    cost = models.CharField(smart_unicode('Costo'), max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, choices=cost_size)

    total_calories =models.DecimalField('Calorie totali', max_digits=9, decimal_places= 2, default=0)
    count_like = models.IntegerField('Likes', default=0)
    count_dontlike = models.IntegerField('Don\'t Likes', default=0)

    # Relation with SignUp for the Author of the Recipe
author_recipe_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='AuthorRecipeUser')

    # Relation with SignUp for the Like/NotLike 
voter_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Likes')

    # Relation N:M with the Ingredients
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through='MadeWith')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

There are some relation to other table but it's not important...

The file that contains EditRecipeForm rsg/src/recipes/forms/update.py

```
from django import forms
from recipes.models import Recipe

class EditRecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
          model = Recipe
          fields = ('name','description','directions','img','difficulty','time_preparation',
                    'time_preparation_min_h','time_cooking','time_cooking_min_h','dose_for',
                    'cost')
```

The view.py file:

```
def recipedit(request, recipe_id):

    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_id)
    form = EditRecipeForm(instance=recipe)

    if request.POST:

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("recipes/profileview.html")

    else:
        form = EditRecipeForm(instance=recipe)


    return render_to_response("recipes/recipedit.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I pass the argument "instance" but the form is empty...

I need help thank you everybody!!

---

This is the template file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel but the problem persists. The form is still empty...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the POST data as well.

```
def recipedit(request, recipe_id):
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_id)    
    if request.POST:
        form = EditRecipeForm(request.POST, instance=recipe)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
```